# Aerospike map operations failing

Tags: java, aerospike

I am starting new project with Aerospike and wanted to test `MapOperation`. But all my tests fail with same error.

Here is example of test

```
    IAerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClientProvider(config).get();

    Key key = new Key("test", "other", "other:1");
    client.delete(client.getWritePolicyDefault(), key);

    Map<Value,Value> inputMap = new HashMap<Value,Value>();
    inputMap.put(Value.get(1), Value.get(55));
    inputMap.put(Value.get(2), Value.get(33));

    // Write values to empty map.
    Record record = client.operate(client.getWritePolicyDefault(), key, 
            MapOperation.putItems(MapPolicy.Default, "mapbin", inputMap));
```

And this is error

```
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error Code 4: Parameter error
at com.aerospike.client.command.ReadCommand.parseResult(ReadCommand.java:121)
at com.aerospike.client.command.SyncCommand.execute(SyncCommand.java:57)
at com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.operate(AerospikeClient.java:697)
at de.ascendro.f4m.server.AerospikeDaoTest.operateMapPut(AerospikeDaoTest.java:207)
```

I am using Aerospike 3.8.2.3 and Aerospike Java client 3.2.4
Do I need specific settings for Aerospike or client to run `MapOperation`?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to run this test.

Problem was that `MapOperation` is supported only from Aerospike version 3.9.1.1